# RewriteRule in clean url for pagination search engine

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, pagination

i have htaccess file and pagination search engine, 
this is my search engine form

```
<form class='fright' method='get' action='hasil_cari=' onsubmit="return false;">

      <input class='srcText' style='padding:6px;'type='text' name='keyword'>
      <input class='submit' style='padding:5;' type='submit' value='find' onclick="window.location.href=this.form.action + this.form.keyword.value;">

</form>
```

this is my RewriteRule for clean url

```
RewriteRule ^admin/keyword=(.*)-page=(.*)$ admin/index.php?h=home&m=find&keyword=$1&p=$2 [L]
```

then i click page 2, but '-page=2' read as keyword , so error message that i had created appear

in address bar of my browser:  `localhost/project/admin/keyword=....-page=2`

"cannot find data = .....-page2"

anyone can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The `.*` matches any character, 0 or more times.

You can specify to ignore the `-` character by using `[^-]*` (the square brackets indicate a range, the caret symbol at the start of the range signify "don't match these") so that the `-page` part of your URL doesn't get swallowed up at part of the keyword:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/keyword=([^-]*)-page=(.*)$ admin/index.php?h=home&m=find&keyword=$1&p=$2 [L]
```

Additionally, if you only want to match numeric page numbers you can do this:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/keyword=([^-]*)-page=([0-9]*)$ admin/index.php?h=home&m=find&keyword=$1&p=$2 [L]
```

Comment: OK, that works fine for me. Have you tried using a different browser to make sure the request isn't being cached? What message/error do you get this time? Are there other htaccess rules?

Comment: same error, if i search 'burger' then i click page 2, same error "cannot find data=burger-page2'

Comment: Is your page 2 link correct? The error message contains `data=burger-page2` (missing a = between page and 2) instead of `data=burger-page=2`

Comment: the link is from looping in my pagination ,i think page 2/3/4 is same